# American pronunciation of constituent

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

In [this entry](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/constituent), is the American pronunciation (as written) correct? Is there any difference between British and American pronunciations?

[image: oald]

Comment: Hey, `kənˈstʃuənt` is kind of fun to say :-)  (I wonder if anyone would be able to figure out what a *constuent* was if you said it to them...)

Comment: there's similar problem with constituency. OALD sometimes is unfair to American English. Also its old versions were firmer with more examples and less mistakes.

Comment: Ahh, that's too bad.  Do you make a habit of cross-referencing multiple dictionaries?  For example, MacMillan gives pronunciations for this word in both [AmE](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/constituent) and [BrE](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/constituent) in IPA.  (Precious few dictionaries of AmE use IPA, unfortunately.)

Comment: OALD have updated their entry, which now gives an identical pronunciation for both BrE and AmE - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/constituent_1?q=constituent - namely /kənˈstɪtʃuənt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch! I do believe that pronunciation is incorrect. Dictionary.com has it as:

> kənˈstɪtʃuənt

The difference between the British and American pronunciations is in the transition between the second and third syllables: the British is a crisper "stit-yu" whereas the American is a softer "sti-chu".

Comment: There is also a difference in the pronunciation of the letter *O*. American pronunciation of it has a kind of long, rising sound like "aa" and British pronunciation of it has a kind of O sound which does not exist in American and Canadian English.

Comment: @Tristan: But unless you are an extremely fastidious speaker who pronounces all your vowels extremely carefully, this 'o' is normally pronounced as schwa (/ə/) in both British and American speech.

Comment: @Tristan I'm American, and I pronounce the first vowel in *constituent* the same way I do the first in *cunning*. I'm curious about this British *O* that you referenced. Do you happen to know where I could find an audio file to listen to it, so I understand what you mean?

Comment: Peter, it's not particularly fastidious, just a common pronunciation.

Comment: Wendi, it's not the same kind of O sound that is in words like *go* and *hope*. It's the O sound that is in words like *hot* and *dog*. American and Canadian pronunciation of it makes those words sound like *haat* and *daag*. British pronunciation of it means those words are not pronounced like that. I don't know how to write them as phonetic symbols but, you can hear the differences in the sound recordings here  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hot_1?q=hot and here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dog_1?q=dog

Comment: Note that it's notoriously difficult to analyze your own pronunciation properly.  We all speak in different styles at different times, and when you pay attention to your own speech it causes a style shift away from your actual vernacular speech patterns.  What Peter Shor says is correct, but it may be hard to realize that it's true if all you're doing is attempting to analyze your own speech.

Comment: @Tristan Just as there are many types of British accents, there are many types of American accents.  Roughly 60% of the U.S. population pronounces two different vowels in *hot* and *dog*; these vowels are /ɑ/ and /ɔ/.  For more information, please see the [low back merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot-caught_merger#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger) on Wikipedia.

Comment: snailboat, it can be difficult. It helps to consider the pronunciation of other people, as well.

Comment: Those vowel sounds that you mentioned are noticeably different from the O sound that I mentioned.